# What is the most secure way to encrypt a zip file?

Tags: server, encryption, gnupg, zip

I wanna encrypt a zip file in Linux so that no one could open or decrypt it with any tool. I mean use an encryption that has no flaw or backdoor. Is **GnuPG-encryption** the best solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "so that no one could open or decrypt it with any tool"  - I know what you meant but usually being *able* to decrypt is an important feature, as long as you have the right key.

Comment: I know this but I mean is there any solution to break encryption without using brute-force or dictionary attack?

Comment: Yes. Abusing flaws in the tool you use. Backdoors. And do not forget thr good "old knife on throat"-method

Comment: So what is the best tool for this goal?

Comment: GnuPG is considered a good tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> an encryption that has no flaw or backdoor

... does not exist.¹

GnuPG is pretty good for encryption. It's the standard tool used for various things in Ubuntu, including signing the packages you install. So if you trust the packages you install, you might as well trust GnuPG as well.

¹ I mean software for encryption, of course. One-time pads are secure.